# reverse week_ref calculation back to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datediff

How can i reverse the following so that it displays the date again:

19th March 2012 should give you a week_ref of: 5855

**EDIT: this is the correct line:**

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start_Week) / 7 AS week_ref   -- create the unique week reference number
```

Comment: You mean get the exact value of "month_date" back again from week 5855?

Comment: no i mean i want to see 03/19/2012

Comment: or Mar-19-2012                     .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
select dateadd(wk, 5855, 0)
```

or this:

```
select dateadd(wk,DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start_Week) / 7, 0)
```

EDIT:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Start_Week) / 7 = 5855
```

Validation test here:

```
SELECT 1  WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, getdate()) / 7 = 5855
```

Comment: i am trying to put this statement after the where clause. how can i do this?

Comment: Thanks but i get "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'"

Comment: @sp-1986 I changed my script. But that problem will be elsewhere in your code. As described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Given a value of 5855, you can only add 5855 x 7 day periods back to 01 Jan 1900. The precise day in the current week will be lost.

There are 40987 days since 19000101, but 5855*7 is 40985. So you've "lost" 2 days.

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, 5855, 0) -- gives 20120319
```

Or if you know kept the day value

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 40987, 0) -- gives 20120321
```

Comment: how do i put this within the where clause?